# How to detect Deferred.await() deadlock?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Consider following code which creates a recursive dependency, because A depends on B, and B depends on A.
Both A and B are supposed to be initialized-once singletons.
Can you suggest a universal method in which this deadlock can be detected early and exception thrown?

I am thinking about either using coroutineContext(I am not sure if it's possible to detect deadlock synchronously this way), or a solution involving channels and a background coroutine detecting deadlock based on channel data - but that's just a theory.

Consider that these tasks can be scheduled either on a single-thread "event loop" executor using runBlocking, or a multi-threaded dispatcher.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun deadlock() = runBlocking {
        lateinit var a: Lazy<Deferred<Unit>>
        lateinit var b: Lazy<Deferred<Unit>>

        a = lazy {
            async { b.value.await() }
        }
        b = lazy {
            async { a.value.await() }
        }
        a.value.await()
    }
```